# XCTest Error XCTAssertEqual failed: ("nil") is not equal to my value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, testing

I am working on an application on IOS and I have finished my application, but I encounter a problem while writing a test. There are two main screens in my application. The first is my main screen where I show the movies, the second is the details screen where I show the details of the movies. There does not appear to be any problem in the test part of the details, but when I want to unit test the search part of my main screen. it gives me this error

> testSearchMovie_whenAPISuccess_showsMovie(): XCTAssertEqual failed: ("nil") is not equal to ("Optional("Blender")")

I can't solve this error and I don't know if I missed something.

There is my test codes.
testSearchMovie_whenAPISuccess_showsMovie() I cannot run my function while testing, the details part works but this part does not work.

```
final class TheMovieAppTests: XCTestCase {
    
    private var movieViewModel: MovieViewModel!
    private var detailViewModel: DetailViewModel!
    
    private var movieService: MockMovieService!
    
    private var movieOutput: MockMovieViewModelOutput!
    private var movieDetailOutput: MockDetailViewModelOutput!
    
    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        movieService = MockMovieService()
        movieViewModel = MovieViewModel(webService: movieService)
        movieOutput = MockMovieViewModelOutput()
        movieViewModel.movieOutput = movieOutput
        
        detailViewModel = DetailViewModel(webService: movieService)
        movieDetailOutput = MockDetailViewModelOutput()
        detailViewModel.detailOutput = movieDetailOutput
        
        
    }
    
    override func tearDownWithError() throws {
        movieViewModel = nil
        detailViewModel = nil
        movieService = nil
    }
    
    func testSearchMovie_whenAPISuccess_showsMovie() throws{
        
        let mockMovieResult = MovieSearchResponse(search: [Movie(Poster: "www", Title: "Blender", Year: "2012", Rated: "123", Released: "1234", Runtime: "111", Genre: "Sci-Fi", Director: "berk berk", Language: "English", Country: "USA", BoxOffice: "12323", Metascore: "123321", imdbRating: "21332", imdbVotes: "123213", imdbID: "1", Plot: "234")])
    
        movieService.fetchMovieMockResult = .success(mockMovieResult)
        print(mockMovieResult)
      
        
        movieViewModel.fetchMovieSearchs(movieName: "Avengers")
        
        print(movieOutput.searchMovie?.search[0].Title)
        
        print(movieOutput.searchMovie?.search[0].Title ?? "Nil Geliyor")
        XCTAssertEqual(movieOutput.searchMovie?.search[0].Title, "Blender")
        
    }
    func testFetchMovieDetail_whenAPISuccess_showsMovieDetail() throws{
        let mockMovieDetails = Movie(Poster: "www", Title: "Avengers", Year: "2014", Rated: "", Released: "", Runtime: "", Genre: "", Director: "", Language: "", Country: "", BoxOffice: "", Metascore: "", imdbRating: "", imdbVotes: "", imdbID: "", Plot: "")
        
        movieService.fetchMovieMockDetails = .success(mockMovieDetails)
        
        detailViewModel.getMovie(id: "1")
        
        XCTAssertEqual(movieDetailOutput.movie?.Poster, "www")
        XCTAssertEqual(movieDetailOutput.movie?.Title, "Avengers")
        XCTAssertEqual(movieDetailOutput.movie?.Year, "2014")
    }
} 

class MockMovieService : MovieService {
    
    var fetchMovieMockResult : Result<MovieSearchResponse, TheMovieApp.CustomError>?
    var fetchMovieMockDetails : Result<Movie, TheMovieApp.CustomError>?
    
    func searchMovies(query: String, completion: @escaping (Result<TheMovieApp.MovieSearchResponse, TheMovieApp.CustomError>) -> ()) {
        if let result = fetchMovieMockResult {
            print("reuslt giriş")
            print(result)
            print("result çıkış")
            completion(result)
        }
    }
    
    func getMovieDetails(imdbID: String, completion: @escaping (Result<TheMovieApp.Movie, TheMovieApp.CustomError>) -> ()) {
        if let result = fetchMovieMockDetails {
           
            completion(result)
        }
    }
} 

class MockMovieViewModelOutput : MovieViewModelOutput {
    var searchMovie : MovieSearchResponse?
    func setSearchMovie(movieList: MovieSearchResponse) {
        print("output giriş")
        print(movieList)
        self.searchMovie = movieList
        print("output çıkış")
        
    }
} 

class MockDetailViewModelOutput : DetailViewModelOutput {
    var movie : Movie?
    func setMovieDetails(movie: TheMovieApp.Movie?, error: String?) {
        self.movie = movie
    }
}
```

Comment: nil is indeed not equal to an optional with a value. Use the debugger. Find out where the two values come from.

Comment: Relevant code should  be included in the question and not posted as a link to an external site.

Comment: I did this, but I couldn't understand why the value I wanted was not coming. Everything seems to be coming correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the reason for the error. The error was caused by using DispatchQueue main in the viewmodel.

Comment: This answer is kind of pointless when there is no code for the view model in the question.